# Passing References by Value in Java

Tags: java, pointers, reference, pass-by-value

```
Dog.setName("Kutta"); // this is how you call a setter method
String Naam = Dog.getName();
System.println(Naam);  //Kutta
Naam = "Kutte ki Ma";
System.println(Dog.getName()); // Is this *Kutte ki Ma* or is it *Kutta*?
```

And Why? If Java passes references by value, shouldn't Naam point to Dog.getName()? If that is the case, shouldn't the Name variable of Dog object (which may be private to the class used here) be directly modified if Naam is modified? Isn't that a flaw?

Comment: `Dog.getName() = "Kutta";` will it compile?

Comment: You need to post code that compiles before it's possible to talk about the execution-time behaviour... Please post a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @hrishirc take a look to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value Pay attention especially to the second best answer, it explains in detail all you need to know.

Comment: Also change Dog.setName() = "Kutta"; to Dog.setName("Kutta");

Comment: The dog's name is "dog"? How creative :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), when you type `Naam = "Kutte ki Ma";` you are not changing the existing string object, you are creating a new one and assigning to your `Naam` variable.

What this means is that the assignment never actually goes anywhere near the dog's name, which still references the previous string. Hence, it doesn't change.

Comment: do you think that their program will execute?

Comment: assuming it was mutable and not a string, say an int?

Comment: @hrishirc `int` is a primitive (so no reference there), and `Integer` (the `Object` wrapper for `int`) is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above, because your code posted here never sets the Dog's name. If you did call

```
Dog.setName("Kutta");
```

Java is pass by value (but the value of an `Object` is it's reference). **But**, `String` is immutable in Java and you cannot update the reference to a `String` held by a different instance.

If you were to use a `StringBuilder` you might do something like,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Dog d = new Dog();
    d.getName().append("Kutta");
    StringBuilder Naam = d.getName();
    System.out.println(Naam);  //Kutta
    Naam.setLength(0);
    Naam.append("Kutte ki Ma");
    System.out.println(d.getName());
}

static class Dog {
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder getName() {
        return sb;
    }
}
```

Which does as you seem to expect.